# Как объединить две переменные в в одну переменную

Tags: php

Есть переменная `$field_1` равная `"Привет"`

И есть переменная `$i`, которая равна `1`

Нужно вывести информацию из `$field_1`

Проблема заключается в том, что мы заведомо не знаем про цифру в переменной $field_**1**

И нужно как-то сначала задать, что `$field_` + `$i` будет равен `$field_1`.
А потом вывести информацию из `$field_1`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, все оказалось на много проще.

```
$field_1 = "Привет";
$fileds = 'field_'.$i;
echo $$fileds;
```

Comment: `echo ${"field_$i"}`

Comment: Всё же, настоятельно рекомендую ознакомиться с массивами и Map/Dictionary. ИМХО, вы создали проблему на пустом месте, и решили её примерно как стоматолог через толстую кишку...